# Why we use Interfaces and the extend the Implement the Interface to the class?

Tags: java, android

why we cant actually do with methods that we made in the class ?
i know how to Implement the Interface and all the methods override in that class.

```
// The callback interface
interface MyCallback {
void callbackCall();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. However don't. You will come to appreciate the consistency that it will bring to your applications. It permits enforcement of common method signatures in relate class i.e. CallbackMother, CallbackGirlfriend, etc.

I find interfaces particularly valuable when rewriting a class. The interface insures that I will not break any link to other classes.

---

In answer to you request for more a more detailed explanation:

The class is the final product. It has parts, "the methods", that do things.

Let say you want to build a class "Airplane". It will do thing - have methods such as land, takeoff, change course, increase altitude, crash, etc.
You could of course just build your airplane. But you might want to draw up a plan first. That's the interface.

Implementing a Java interface forces you to respect you plan - this will avoid mistakes. When you discover that you want to change plan, you will have to update your plan - i.e. modify the interface. You will do less mistakes and same time.

Other benefits are:

- Achieve consistency across similar classes by sharing common interface.
- Makes it easier to modify a class with breaking other classes that use it.
- Provide a way to provide multiple inheritance (something C++ allow but Java 
  does not)
- Interfaces are used extensively in some frameworks do funky stuff like 
  dependency injection.

As you start doing more complex stuff, you will have no choice but to at least use some the standard Java interfaces: Serializable, Observable, Iterable.

Since your already know the how, use it even if it currently seems overkill. It will pay off.

Comment: why you rewrite the class?

Comment: Usually, to improve it.

Comment: seriously i this explanation is not enough ... Please explain more with simple way , i am new to developing.

Comment: Re-read my post. I've added more stuff to it.

Comment: yes .. you explained well, Thanks for that. Can i contact you with 1 more Question sir?

Comment: Sure - please do.

Comment: please text me irfanyaqub71@gmail.com